# Removing Characters from python Output

Tags: python, apache-spark

I did alot of work to remove the characters from the spark python output like **u u' u" [()/'"** which are creating problem for me to do the further work. So please put a focus on the same .

I have the input like,

```
(u"(u'[25145,   12345678'", 0.0)
(u"(u'[25146,   25487963'", 43.0) when i applied code to summing out the result. this gives me the output like
(u'(u"(u\'[54879,    5125478\'"', 0.0)
(u"(u'[25145,   25145879'", 11.0)
(u'(u"(u\'[56897,    22548793\'"', 0.0) so i want to remove all the character like (u'(u"(u\'["'')
```

I want output like

```
54879,5125478,0.0

25145,25145879,11.0
```

the code is i tried is

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import os
import sys

sc = SparkContext("local", "aggregate")

file1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/data/first/part-00000")
file2 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/data/second/part-00000")

file3 = file1.union(file2).coalesce(1).map(lambda line: line.split(','))

result = file3.map(lambda x: ((x[0]+', '+x[1],float(x[2][:-1])))).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b).coalesce(1)

result.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/Test1")
```

Comment: What is the result of your code?

Comment: this code is for aggregating the result based on the key output coming is fine but it contains some  u u' u" [()/'" chracter those i want to remove.the output is like (u'(u"(u\'[54879,    5125478\'"', 0.0)
(u"(u'[25145,   25145879'", 11.0). so i want to remove all the characters and want output like 54879,5125478,0.0

25145,25145879,11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only problem is that you have to reformat you result before saving it to the file, i.e. something like:

```
result.map(lambda x:x[0]+','+str(x[1])).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/Test1")
```

Comment: Thanks mark but it is giving me the error,  result.map(lambda x:x[0]+','+x[1]).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/Test1")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found

Comment: This is because `x[1]` is a float: you need to convert it to string. I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: But are those characters in the input too?

Comment: yes Mark, the input file contains (u"(u'[25145,   12345678'", 0.0)
(u"(u'[25146,   25487963'", 43.0) when i applied the my code it is giving the output like (u'(u"(u\'[54879, 5125478\'"', 0.0) (u"(u'[25145, 25145879'", 11.0) m wondering from where / are coming and also want to remove all the character

Comment: import string

s = "@John, It's a fantastic #week-end%, How about () you"
for c in "!@#%&*()[]{}/?<>":
    s = string.replace(s, c, "")

print s   how can i use this in my code

Comment: if you just want to have a dirty solution like the code you have put in the comment you just need to include it in a map function after the `textFile` function..