# Removing characters from array python

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array and would like to keep just the numbers.

```
[array([-0.69]), array([-0.82]), array([ 0.00268447]),
 array([ 1.25709725]), array([ 0.00460194]), array([-0.00191748])]
```

I have tried strip and replace commands but to no avail. I have also followed this : [Removing Characters from python Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998530/removing-characters-from-python-output) . Any more ideas?

Comment: `array` as in `numpy.array`?

Comment: That is a list of arrays (probably numpy arrays). There are no characters that you could strip. Do you want a list of numbers or an array of numbers?

Comment: To clarify: You seem to have a list of numpy.arrays with one element each.

Comment: Whats the output you want?

Comment: Would this be a similar example? Turning `[[123], [2], [79]]` into `[123, 2, 79]`?

Comment: I want an array with -0.69, -0.82, 0.00268447 etc

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a list of numpy.arrays with a single element each. You can turn that into a numpy.array like this:

```
l = [array([-0.69]), array([-0.82]), array([ 0.00268447]),
    array([ 1.25709725]), array([ 0.00460194]), array([-0.00191748])]
arr = numpy.array(l)
```

To print this array, you could do this:

```
print(', '.join(map(str, arr)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting each element to `float`.

```
In [1]: from numpy import array
In [2]: a = [array([-0.69]), array([-0.82]), array([ 0.00268447]),
   ....:  array([ 1.25709725]), array([ 0.00460194]), array([-0.00191748])]

In [3]: map(float,a)
Out[1]: [-0.69, -0.82, 0.00268447, 1.25709725, 0.00460194, -0.00191748]
```

You can do like this.